# RightClick menu on ListView UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10

I have a code that calls the context menu by right mouse button.

```
private void GridColections_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MenuFlyout myFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
        MenuFlyoutItem firstItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "OneIt" };
        MenuFlyoutItem secondItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "TwoIt" };
        myFlyout.Items.Add(firstItem);
        myFlyout.Items.Add(secondItem);
        FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        myFlyout.ShowAt(senderElement);
    }
```

But the menu appears in the center of my listview. Not at the place where I clicked on the mouse. How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the Flyout show at your mouse click point,and you can use the `ShowAt(UIElement,Point)` rather `ShowAt(FrameworkElement)`.

The code that can show the Flyout in your Click point.

```
     private void GridColection_OnRightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         MenuFlyout myFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
         MenuFlyoutItem firstItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "OneIt" };
         MenuFlyoutItem secondItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "TwoIt" };
         myFlyout.Items.Add(firstItem);
         myFlyout.Items.Add(secondItem);

         //if you only want to show in left or buttom 
         //myFlyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Left;

         FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;

         //the code can show the flyout in your mouse click 
         myFlyout.ShowAt(sender as UIElement, e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement));
     }
```

[image]